# Location of inodes (ext)?

Tags: filesystems, ext3, inode

Say I want to observe how the flow from file name to cluster on hard disc goes.

I get the inode number of I file (which is mapped in a directory data):

```
1863 autorun.inf
```

So, now i know that i have to look for the inode numbered `1863` which will contain the pointers to the data on the hard disc.

Where is the inode data located and how does the os know where to find it?

Comment: Short ans:- An inode is a data structure on a traditional Unix-style file system such as UFS or ext3 and kernel access file by inode.

Comment: @RahulPatil Does that mean that they are never written on a disk?

Comment: when you mount then it's load into the memory from disk

Comment: @Alan, they are certainly written to disk. The inode on disk _is_ the file (it holds the permissions, owner, group, modification times, and other assorted information on the file). When the file is opened, it is loaded into memory for fast access, that is all. The filesystem reserves some space on disk to keep inodes (if you look at mke2fs(8), it says you can say how many to reserve). Exactly where they are placed, and their exact contents, depends on the filesystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inode data are usually scattered around the disk (in order to cut down seeks). Being able to tell where the inode structures are is the core functionality of a filesystem driver - check [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.7.3/fs/ext3/) for current implementation of ext3 in Linux) or [e2fsprogs](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=summary) sources if you are interested in details.

From a user's perspective you might want to take a look at `dumpe2fs` which will give you some information about a ext2-based (ext3/ext4) filesystem structure.

Comment: +1 for `dumpe2fs`.  You can also play around interactively with `debugfs` instead.  You can learn a lot playing with these tools.

Comment: Just be careful, one ill-advised write can destoy the filesystem. Better fool around with a throwaway filesystem created on a loopback.

Answer (score 0):

The inode number points to an entry in the inode table on disk. This entry holds some information about the file, like file mode, uid/gid, number of links, ctime, mtime, atime and the disk block addresses, which may contain direct blocks, indirect blocks and double indirect blocks. See the following link for more information:

```
http://140.120.7.20/LinuxKernel/LinuxKernel/node17.html
```